# Paypal Pro and chained payments and Credit Card Processing

Tags: paypal

We have integrated chained payments on our website, which means payment goes to multiple recipients.  I would love to be able to process credit cards directly on our website, and still be able to do the chained payments for our affiliates.

How is this done?

I believe chained payments is not possible when processing credit cards directly on the website with Paypal Pro.  One idea is to collect all the payments with PayPal Pro and at the end of the month do a mass pay and payout all the third parties.

The reason we do chained payments is to give paypal 2.9% of their cut.  Without the chained payments we would suffer from 2.9% and another 2.9% sending to another recipient.

What is the best way of doing chained payments and credit card processing (doesn't have to be paypal)?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about payment processing.

Comment: In his defense, PayPal refers people here to ask general questions like this.  Then they get here and people tell them it's not relevant, and vote their stuff down.  PayPal and Stack need to get together on this and either open this tag up for more general questions, or tell PayPal to stop leading people here and setup their own developer community.  This is just going to keep happening until one of those two things happens.

Comment: @AndrewAngell I'm aware of the references on the Paypal site. I agree that it's not ideal, but Paypal aren't the only ones doing this. Nevertheless, [so] does have its own rules on what is and is not on topic, and this is outside the remit. We shouldn't be handling off-topic questions just because some other site says we do.

Comment: @MikeW, the PayPal logo on their tag means it's a sponsored tag, right?  Which means PayPal is paying Stack some sort of a fee/bonus or whatever you want to call it to tag this section of their site and utilize. And then they're directing people here for general questions.  Stack shouldn't be taking payments from sponsors who aren't going to follow their guidelines, or they should adjust the guidelines accordingly.  Right now the ones getting punished are the ones simply looking for help and getting the run-around.

Comment: @AndrewAngell Yes - some people get the run around. Blame Paypal for the wording on their site that encourages people to post questions here that are off-topic. If you want to debate this further, raise a question on [meta], but check [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173138/226287) first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, split payments in general don't work with Payments Pro.  You could actually just turn it into 2 separate payments and make 2 separate Pro requests...one on your behalf and another on the 3rd parties behalf, but then the card holder would see 2 separate transactions on their statement so that could cause confusion.

You could do like you said, too, and distribute with MassPay.  When you send with MassPay you won't get hit with another 2.9%  It has a different structure where it charges the sender, but the maximum per transaction is 1.00 no matter what the amount is.  You can work all those fees into your agreements with affiliates and just send them what they would end up if they were eating the fees.

Definitely frustrating, but when dealing with credit cards directly there just really isn't any service out there that will do it like a chained payment does.  PayPal has their Adaptive Payments platform, and Amazon has something similar, too, but I don't even know of any others.